# 2 seperate relational tables or just one relational table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a users table and at the moment a table for storing the users information. The users have a role of buyer or as seller. where the seller has some additional fields that the buyer doesn't have.

Now im wondering what will be a good approach to use. create a table for the users information where i refer to the users id, or two separated tables. One table for the buyers information referring to the user id and one for the sellers information with the exta fields referring to the user id. Where you fill the table according to the users role.

There will be millions of users inside this table so thats something to keep in mind here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you put all the information both types of users share  (and that fits on one records of course) in the User table. Then if you need more information by type create a table for that type. If you only need more information right now for sellers, then create a sellers table. If buyers also have specialized fields, then create a buyers table.  If however, you do not at this time have any specialized fields to add for the buyers table, then you may not need one at this time. It can be added later if your data model changes.

If this table (these tables) is going to be in a one-to-one relationship with the User table, then make sure to create the Userid as both the FK (to users)and the PK of the child table to maintain data integrity.

Comment: Thanks! i ended up using this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use two tables, one for users and the other for associates

### users

+id

user_name

...

### associates

+id

user_id

assoc_type //buyer or seller
...